# A java program to calculate the perimeter of a square,circle,rectangle and Triangle

Tags: java

I was given an assignment to perform method overloading in inheritence in java by designing a program that calculates the perimeter of different shapes, i designed code as shown below but when i try to compile, there are errors.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Perimeter {
public double getperimeter(int constant,double pi,double radius){
return(constant*pi*radius);
}
public double getperimeter(int sconstant,double length){
return(sconstant*length);
}
public double getperimeter(int rconstant,double rlength,double widith){
return(rconstant*(rlength+widith));
}
public double getperimeter(double base,double height,double hypotenuse){
return(base+height+hypotenuse);
}
public void main (String args []){
final double pi=22/7;
final int constant=2;
double raduius;

final int sconstant=4;
double length;

final int rconstant=2;
double rlength;
double widith;

double base;
double height;
double hypotenuse;

Perimeter g= new Perimeter();
Scanner s=new scanner(System.in);
 System.out.println("Enter The Radius");
 g.radius=s.nextDouble();
 System.out.println("Enter The Square Length");
 g.lenght=s.nextInt();
 System.out.println("Enter The Rectangle Lenght");
 g.rlength=s.nextInt();
 System.out.println("Enter The Rectangle widith");
 g.widith=s.nextInt();
 System.out.println("Enter The Triangle Base");
 g.base=s.nextInt();
 System.out.println("Enter The Triangle height");
 g.height=s.nextInt();
 System.out.println("Enter The Triangle hypotenuse");
 g.hypotenuse=s.nextInt();

System.out.println("Perimeter = " + g.getperimeter(constant,pi,radius));
System.out.println("Perimeter = " + g.getperimeter(sconstant,length));
System.out.println("Perimeter = " + g.getperimeter(rconstant,rlength,widith));
System.out.println("Perimeter = " + g.getperimeter(base,height,hypotenuse));
```

Comment: is this **spot the error contest** ?? then, i can spot one error, you have no closing brace for your main and your class.. :P

Comment: and his main method is not static void, it's just void.

Comment: IT would help to know what are the errors you get.

Comment: Your code doesn't use inheritance at all, and overloading doesn't have much to do with inheritance. My guess is that you should use polymorphism instead, and *override* the abstract method `computePerimeter()` in the subclasses of the class Shape (which would be Square, Triangle, etc.)

Answer (score 5):

This is a "classic" overriding problem that academics love.  (Others involve animals or vehicles.)

Start with a `Shape` interface:

```
public interface Shape {
    double getPerimeter();
}
```

Then have subclasses implement it, each in their own way:

```
public class Rectangle implements Shape {
    private double height;
    private double width;

    public Rectangle(double w, double h) {
        this.width = w;
        this.height = h;
    }

    public double getPerimeter() { return 2.0*(this.width + this.height); }
}


public class Circle implements Shape {
    private double radius; 

    public Circle(double r) {
        this.radius = r; 
    }

    public double getPerimeter() { return 2.0*Math.PI*this.radius; }
}
```

You'll be able to do things like this:

```
List<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();
shapes.add(new Rectangle(1.0, 2.0));
shapes.add(new Circle(10.0));
for (Shape shape : shapes) {
    System.out.println(shape.getPerimeter()); // every Shape will do it their own way
}
```

Add a new Shape implementation and your original code still just works.  It's the essence of polymorphism and dynamic binding.

Answer (score 4):

You are defining two methods with same signature within a single class. This is an error. Your methods :

```
double getperimeter(int constant,double pi,double radius);
double getperimeter(int rconstant,double rlength,double widith);
```

Also your main method must be declared as static

Comment: This is not the only error he has btw.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you should have a the class Perimeter in a different file.
I see missing brackets closing the class Perimeter.
Also like Xavier mentioned you have two methods with the same signature.
You are also reading values from Scanner into Perimeter instance variables and then passing the uninitialized values to the Perimeter methods.
So i would separate the Perimeter class and in the main read the values to local variables and pass them to Perimeter methods.

```
public void main (String args []){
final double pi=22/7;
final int constant=2;
double raduius;

final int sconstant=4;
double length;

final int rconstant=2;
double rlength;
double widith;

double base;
double height;
double hypotenuse;

Perimeter g= new Perimeter();
Scanner s=new scanner(System.in);
 System.out.println("Enter The Radius");
 radius=s.nextDouble();
 System.out.println("Enter The Square Length");
 lenght=s.nextInt();
 System.out.println("Enter The Rectangle Lenght");
 rlength=s.nextInt();
 System.out.println("Enter The Rectangle widith");
 widith=s.nextInt();
 System.out.println("Enter The Triangle Base");
 base=s.nextInt();
 System.out.println("Enter The Triangle height");
 height=s.nextInt();
 System.out.println("Enter The Triangle hypotenuse");
 hypotenuse=s.nextInt();

System.out.println("Perimeter = " + g.getperimeter(constant,pi,radius));
System.out.println("Perimeter = " + g.getperimeter(sconstant,length));
System.out.println("Perimeter = " + g.getperimeter(rconstant,rlength,widith));
System.out.println("Perimeter = " + g.getperimeter(base,height,hypotenuse));
```

Comment: You're kidding, right?  double pi = 22/7?  Really?  When Math.PI is available?  And 22/7 = 3 in integer arithmetic.

Comment: Wasn't even correcting that. It's quoted from question. But yes you are right that's ugly calculation.

Answer (score 0):

You are still unfamiliar with java it seems, hence start help:

- The main method is static, that is executed first.
- You are using overloaded methods getperimeter, where you can easily mix up int and double. Maybe pick a unique name. Java convention is to use funny camel case: getPerimeter.

  ```
  import java.util.*;

  public class Perimeter {

  public static void main(String args[]) {
      new Perimeter().execute();
  }

  public double getperimeter(int constant, double pi, double radius) {
      return (constant * pi * radius);
  }

  public double getperimeter(int sconstant, double length) {
      return (sconstant * length);
  }

  public double getperimeterRLenghtWidith(int rconstant, double rlength, double widith) {
      return (rconstant * (rlength + widith));
  }

  public double getperimeter(double base, double height, double hypotenuse) {
      return (base + height + hypotenuse);
  }

  private void execute() {
      final double pi = Math.PI; //22 / 7;
      final int constant = 2;
      double radius;

      final int sconstant = 4;
      double length;

      final int rconstant = 2;
      double rlength;
      double widith;

      double base;
      double height;
      double hypotenuse;

      Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter The Radius");
      radius = s.nextDouble();
      System.out.println("Enter The Square Length");
      length = s.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Enter The Rectangle Lenght");
      rlength = s.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Ener The Rectangle widith");
      widith = s.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Enter The Triangle Base");
      base = s.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Enter The Triangle height");
      height = s.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Enter The Triangle hypotenuse");
      hypotenuse = s.nextInt();

      System.out.println("Perimeter = " + getperimeter(constant, pi, radius));
      System.out.println("Perimeter = " + getperimeter(sconstant, length));
      System.out.println("Perimeter = " + getperimeterRLenghtWidith(rconstant, rlength, widith));
      System.out.println("Perimeter = " + getperimeter(base, height, hypotenuse));

  }
  }
  ```